# How to set android layout height to x% of its parent height?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I would like to create this simple layout:

[image]

I wrote this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/purple_200">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:background="@color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But doing so I don't see any black view appearing. What am I missing?

Comment: using linear layout is an outdated approach, use constraint layout instead

Comment: You're close.  You just need to add another child after the inner LinearLayout to take up the remaining 0.7 and assigning layout_weight=0.7 to it.

Comment: @MichaelKrause Not really, it's not good to add an empty child just for that when the desired behavior exists natively; it just has to set the parent layout `android:weightSum="1"`, as I showed in my answer.

Comment: But if you don't have another child the linear layout is essentially going to ignore the layout weight and assign all of the height to the one child.

Comment: No, that happens only if you don't set the weightSum, because, by default, it's calculated as the sum of all the children's weights; but if you set it at to bigger value, it will be calculated as expected, keeping the ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new way called `ConstraintLayout` which is preferred. You can use `layout_constraintHeight_percent` property of it.

**Example**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/purple_200"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Output:**

[image: SS]

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to add

```
android:weightSum="1"
```

to your parent's layout, so

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="@color/purple_200">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:background="@color/black" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I suppose you thought it's 1 by default, but it's not, you have to specify it, otherwise, it's calculated as the sum of the children's weights, so in this case, it was 0.3.

From the [android:weightSum](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout#attr_android:weightSum)'s definition:

> Defines the maximum weight sum. If unspecified, the sum is computed by
> adding the layout_weight of all of the children. This can be used for
> instance to give a single child 50% of the total available space by
> giving it a layout_weight of 0.5 and setting the weightSum to 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Other solution is ***androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline***. You can add a guideline to a constraintLayout, and you can change ***app:layout_constraintGuide_percent*** variable between 0..1 range. You can change orientation too.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```